# Translating a gridded csv file with numpy

Tags: python, parsing, numpy

I need to get some meteorological data into a MySQL database. 
File `inputFile.csv` is a comma-delimited list of values. There are 241 lines and 481 values per line.
Each line maps to a certain latitude, and each value's position within the line maps to a certain longitude.

There are two additional files with the same structure, `lat.csv` and `lon.csv`. These files contain the coordinates that the values in `inputFile.csv` map to.

So to find the latitude and longitude for a value in `inputFile.csv`, we need to refer to the values at the same line/position (or row/column) within `lat.csv` and `lon.csv`

I want to translate `inputFile.csv` using `lat.csv` and `lon.csv` such that my output file contains a list of *values* (from `inputFile.csv`),*latitudes*, and *longitudes*.

Here is a small visual example:

```
    inputFile.csv
    3,5,1,4,5
    1,4,1,2,5
    5,7,3,8,0

    lat.csv
    22,31,51,21,52
    55,21,24,66,12
    11,23,12,55,55

    lon.csv
    12,35,12,52,11
    35,11,25,33,42
    62,53,45,25,54


    output:
    val lat lon
    3   22  12
    5   31  35
    1   51  12
    4   21  52
    5   52  11 
    1   55  35
    4   21  11
    1   24  25  
    2   66  33
    etc
```

What is the best way to do this in python/numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that since you know the total size the the array that you want, you can preallocate it:

```
a = np.empty((241*481,3))
```

Now you can add the data:

```
for i,fname in enumerate(('inputFile.csv','lat.csv','lon.csv')):
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = np.fromfile(f,sep=',')
        a[:,i] = data.ravel()
```

---

If you don't know the number of elements up front, you can generate a 2-d list instead (a list of `np.ndarrays`):

```
alist = []
for fname in ('inputFile.csv','lat.csv','lon.csv'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = np.fromfile(f,sep=',')
        alist.append( data.ravel() )
a = np.array(alist).T
```

Comment: I suppose the `with open(fname) ...` stuff isn't really necessary as `numpy` will accept a filename in `np.fromfile` ...

Comment: Your second solution seems to work, but for the first solution I get "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"

Comment: Also for some reason the length of the output of your second solution is 1 greater than the input length.

Comment: @Mike -- To me, those symptoms imply that one row in your files is 1 element too long.

Answer (score 2):

Only with numpy functions:

```
import numpy as np

inputFile = np.gentfromtxt('inputFile.csv',delimiter = ',')
inputFile.reshape(-1)
lat = np.gentfromtxt('lat.csv',delimiter = ',')
lat.reshape(-1)
lon = np.gentfromtxt('lon.csv',delimiter = ',')
lon.reshape(-1)

output = np.vstack( (inputFile,lat,lon) )
```